# Python - while loop - beginner

Tags: python, while-loop

I don't understand why in this example of a while loop `i=1`?
I assumed that it starts from index `0`, but when I put `i=0` the result is wrong (it prints `10` two times in the beginning).

```
PlayListRatings = [10, 9.5, 10, 8, 7.5, 5, 10, 10]

i = 1
Rating = PlayListRatings[0]
while(Rating >= 6):
    print(Rating)
    Rating = PlayListRatings[i]
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: Because you coded like that, and it is because `Rating = PlayListRatings[0]` already hard coded `0` in code has mentioned

Comment: Because when `i=0` you are updating `Rating` in the first iteration with `i=0` again before you actually increase the counter, so it is printing it twixe

Comment: please upvote the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is starting from z1z because it is initializing `Rating` outside the loop by assigning the first element (index 0) of the list.

If you put `i=0`, inside the loop at the first iteration it does `print(Rating)` then reassign `Rating = PlayListRatings[i]` but the index has not been incremented yet so at the next print `Rating` is still the first element.

If you move `Rating = PlayListRatings[i]` after the increment then it should work:

```
i = 0
Rating = PlayListRatings[0]
while(Rating >= 6):
    print(Rating)
    i = i + 1
    Rating = PlayListRatings[i]
```

Or actually:

```
i = 0
while True:
    Rating = PlayListRatings[i]
    if (Rating<6):
        break
    print(Rating)
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: in second case, you still have to set `Rating` to an initial value, otherwise `Rating` is unknown in the `while`-header at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply functional programming if you are open for it:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x >= 6, [10, 9.5, 10, 8, 7.5, 5, 10, 10]))
[10, 9.5, 10, 8, 7.5]
```